# FullCalendar Need to Drag All Day and Hourly Events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar for my project and all is working fine so far. The only behavior I want to address is the capacity to grad an event across days. Events flaged as All Day can be dragged up or down across the calendar days. Events not flaged as All Day cannot. Both can be dropped no problem.

How can I make hourly events 'draggable'.

here a snippet of the code that handles the dropping and resizing

```
                editable: true,
            eventResize: function (event) {
                var data = {
                    EventID: event.eventID,
                    Subject: event.title,
                    Start: event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                    End: event.end != null ? event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : null,
                    Description: event.description,
                    ThemeColor: event.color,
                    IsFullDay: event.allDay
                };
                SaveEvent(data);
            },
            editable: true,
            eventDrop: function (event) {
                var data = {
                    EventID: event.eventID,
                    Subject: event.title,
                    Start: event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                    End: event.end != null ? event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : null,
                    Description: event.description,
                    ThemeColor: event.color,
                    IsFullDay: event.allDay
                };
                SaveEvent(data);
```

Comment: timed and all-day events should all be draggable anywhere on the calendar. This is true at least in the agenda view. In a "month" view you can't drag timed events because there are no times on the calendar, so it would not be clear what time you wanted to change it to. Can you be a bit clearer about the scenario where you're having a problem, and/or maybe show us enough code to reproduce the problem. You could even make us a runnable demo - here's a basic template to start from: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/168/

Comment: ADyson, i missed that detail. The behaviour is true on the monthly view only and for just reasons as you have pointed out. I little set back of working too late at night. Thank you